# How set wheelZoomRate in ReactMapGL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, react-map-gl

In mapbox gl wheelZoomRate can be set with the **setWheelZoomRate** method. How can achieve same effect if ReactMapGL Map.

```
map.scrollZoom.setWheelZoomRate(1 / 600);
```

I have tried with set the wheelZoomRate with **scrollZoom** prop of React Map GL Map.

```
scrollZoom={{
              wheelZoomRate: 1/300,
              enable: { 
               around: 'center',
               wheelZoomRate: 1/300
              }
           }}
```

But it seems no effect on wheelZoomRate of the map while scrolling.